# How would you update multiple fields in a table at once using SQL in Visual Basic 2008?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my current line of code but it does not seem to work.

Str = " UPDATE tblTest SET SetTest = FALSE WHERE SetTest = TRUE"

The purpose of the code is to set all values in SetTest as false using boolean. I'm not sure if this is correct as my database is not being updated. I'm using visual basic 2008.

This is the code I'm working from

```
Private Sub btnSetTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSetTest.Click
    Dim Str As String
    Str = "SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE SetTest = True"
    dtasetSpellingBee.Tables("tblTest").Rows(CurrentRowNo)("SetTest") = "TRUE"
    dtaadpTest.Update(dtasetSpellingBee, "tblTest")
    'Record has been saved so make add record false now
    AddRecord = False
    'Update the Student detail table in the database
    MessageBox.Show("The update has been saved to disk", "Save Updates", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub



Private Sub frmStudent_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conDatabase()

    ' Create an SqlCommand object to use the DataAdapter for the Account table to retrieve its records from the database into the DataSet
    dtaadpTest.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand
    ' Assign the Connection object to the DataAdapter so it knows what database to retrieve the records from
    dtaadpTest.SelectCommand.Connection = conSpellingBee
    ' Create a query which will retrieve no records from the Account table but will
    ' add a table to the DataSet with the same fields
    dtaadpTest.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE TestID = 0"
    ' Execute the SqlCommand to fill a table called tblTest in the DataSet
    dtaadpTest.Fill(dtasetSpellingBee, "tblTest")

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get if you execute `SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE SetTest = True`? Are there any rows returned? Also, SQL dialect matters, so make sure you add a tag for the type of database you're using to future questions like this one. I've added the `ms-access` tag for you based on your comment to @jods below.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not entirely sure on what you mean. I'm a novice coder.

Comment: Oh so you use a Dataset. That makes me want to ask: how is your DataAdapter configured? Also, your question was about updating multiple rows at once with a SQL UPDATE query, the code you posted in your edited question only updates a single row with a DataSet, what gives?

Comment: I mean specifically what I asked you to do - execute a SELECT to see if the syntax is proper for your database and to determine whether you have data that meets the specified criteria. You can't update data that doesn't meet the criteria in the WHERE clause, so the first step is to find out *if there are rows to be updated* in the first place. (If you don't know how to *read* data from the database, it's probably not a good idea for you to be altering it yet.)

Comment: I want everything to be set to false in the SetTest column to be set to false when I activate the button. This is so only one thing at a time is set to true. I'm going to use it at a later time.

Comment: I understand now Ken White. I've ran the code and I haven't encountered any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your SQL dialect (you don't say).

Assuming you use MS SQL Server, `SetTest` would be a `bit` type, which has values 1 and 0. So this query should be:

```
UPDATE tablTest SET SetTest = 0 WHERE SetTest = 1
```

Comment: I'm using microsoft access for my database.

Comment: Sorry I am not a Access user myself, can't really help here. What's the error you get when you execute the request anyway?

Comment: I don't get an error but when I check my table it doesn't get updated. Everything stays the same.

Comment: Can you show the code that executes the SQL request? Did you check the number of affected rows (that's what `ExecuteNonQuery` returns).